# Mathematical grid reference with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Good afternoon, I want to plot a mathematical grid reference using the following code:

```
from matplotlib.axis import Axis
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, ScalarFormatter


spacing = 0.1
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()


major_tick = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4]
minor_tick = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]

ax.set_xticks(major_tick,)
ax.set_xticks(minor_tick, minor=True)

ax.set_yticks(major_tick)
ax.set_yticks(minor_tick, minor=True)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(spacing))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(spacing))

ax.grid(which='both')

ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=1)
ax.grid(which='major', alpha=1)

plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

The boxes are not squares. Is there a way to do it?

And this is what I want to archive:
[image]

Comment: set aspect to `1`: `ax = fig.add_subplot(aspect=1)`

Comment: @Stef it looks fine now the width has decreased but I want it to be twice the height.

Comment: in this case set aspect to 2 and x ticks from 1 to 8 instead of 1 to 4